# how do I find a list of files committed to a git branch?

Tags: git, git-svn, commit

How do I list all the files that I committed to a specific branch? I've committed about 40+ files to a branch, and I need to find the file names because I am trying to debug something, hard to do when I don't remember the file names.

`git log` only gives me a long list of commits but not the actual files.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Have you tried git ls-tree?

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r <branch_name>
```

--name-only gives you just the file names.
-r recurses into sub directories.

If you want the name of the sub-directory listed before recursing into it, add -t to the argument list.

Comment: Wonderful answer. The question you answered is not immediately obvious, and I do know about git log.

Comment: i got list of tons of files instead of just few from my branch. `git log --name-only` looks like the appropriate answer to see files modified by commits in the branch

Comment: @Eugene: A down vote is a bit harsh, don't you think?

Comment: @Carl because ? i think that answer is wrong and offered solution doesn't work i should up vote it ? i have up voted the answer below. this is the purpose of these 2 arrows - to outline the best solution which is appropriate for the most of users.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: `git ls-tree --name-only $branch $directory/` for a list of a specific directory

Answer (score 24):

`git log --name-only` worked for me.

Comment: This was the only answer that seems to actually address the question.  Thanks!

Comment: this should be the approved answer

Comment: After running this command we were not able to exit, so found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483757/how-to-exit-git-log-or-git-diff

Answer (score 22):

If your branch was derived from `master` you can use this command to list all new files that where added after branching:

```
git diff master...new-branch --name-status --diff-filter=A
```

Available filter for `--diff-filter` are:

```
Added (A), Copied (C), Deleted (D), Modified (M), Renamed (R)
```

Comment: I you expect to get some help, you should provide more information. Do you get wrong output? Do you get an error?

Comment: This worked for me. I created a branch, made some commits and was looking for only the modified files. The ls-tree solution gave me all the files in my initial checkout - dunno why - but this gave me only the modified files in the new branch. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Very nice! Can also be used between different remotes: `git diff upstream/master...my-branch --name-status`

Answer (score 12):

The [`git ls-files`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-ls-files.html) command lists all the files that exist in the latest commit on the current branch.

Or, you can use `git diff --name-only` to show a list of the files that are different between any two arbitrary commits.

Answer (score 8):

`git log --name-status` will give the names and status of changed files in each commit

Comment: by name you mean the branch name?

Comment: perfect answer , briliant

Answer (score 2):

```
git log --name-only
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This one can be useful, if you want to know all distinct files that got modified since branching:

> git log --name-status develop...branchname | grep -E "^[AMD]\s" |
>   sort -u

And this variant will list the subset of them that *you* modified:

> git log --name-status develop...branchname --author= |
>   grep -E "^[AMD]\s" | sort -u

Answer (score -1):

try using [smartgit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html). it is gui client for git. it has very useful UI and is free for non-commercial use.

Comment: This didn't answer his question directly, but the information is useful. Thanks.

Comment: Soooo, how do you use smartgit to see what files have been committed?  That would actually answer the question.

Comment: @Scott Biggs, see log with `ctrl+L` for repository, folder or file. In logs windows *select two commits* to see diff between them with list of files, and compare pane.

Answer (score -2):

```
git diff development...crmq-2405 --name-status --diff-filter=A
```

will list all files that have been added to the new branch that are not in the mail - in this case `development` main branch.

```
git diff development...crmq-2405 --name-status
```

This variant will show all files in the new branch

Generic form:

```
git diff main_branch...new_branch --name-status
```

and yes, order does matter.

Comment: I think this is being downvoted because the parameters are in fact backward. I got zero results for `development…base`, but `git diff base..development --name-status --diff-filter=A` did list off the four new files in my dev branch.