# How to exit git log or git diff

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log

I'm trying to learn Git with the help of [Git Immersion](http://gitimmersion.com/).
There's one thing that frustrates me whenever I use `git log` or `git diff`:

[image: Git log shows (END) marker]

I can't figure out what to do next when I encounter this `(END)` word.

I can't type any commands, and I end up closing the current Bash window and open another. How do I type in the next command that I want to use?

Comment: Even after I use q+Enter to quit, the <END> reappears every time I begin typing again. It eats up my first character. Thereafter, I'm able to type the command I want. However, I'd rather not have this behavior at all. I'm on Windows. Suggestions?

Comment: Windows users: you must type q+enter first.  Once you escape with cntl+c, you'll be stuck in that weird loop.  Use ONLY q+enter to exit.

Comment: It's possible to break out by repeatedly typing q+enter+q+enter+q+enter until the end of time no matter what the console shows.

Comment: I fixed it by using another console, typing "ps" to find all the processes, then typing "kill -9 <PID for the less command>" to kill less.  Nothing else worked.

Comment: just press ( :qa ) without parentheses and hit Enter, it will exit.

Comment: @KodiakMx brought me here too but its seven years after ptkvsk and 43 other users agreed with him

Comment: Usually you just curse and then close the window, the answers below provide better options though

Answer (score 1987, accepted):

You're in the `less` program, which makes the output of `git log` scrollable.

Type <kbd>q</kbd> to exit this screen. Type <kbd>h</kbd> to get help.

If you don't want to read the output in a pager and want it to be just printed to the terminal define the environment variable `GIT_PAGER` to `cat` or set `core.pager` to `cat` (execute `git config --global core.pager cat`).

Comment: I kept on pressing q: as one would do to get out of vi! Thanks!

Comment: @Affan: To quit vi use `:q`. `q:` opens a command window which can be exited with `:q` (but this won't quit vi then).

Comment: Simplest way to avoid the pager just once: "git log | cat". I also like to do "git log > /tmp/foo" and then view /tmp/foo in the editor of my choice. For some reason, that works better for me.

Comment: `q` was the first thing I tried because some other git command needs it to exit; it definitely does not work for `git log`.

Comment: q: was what I needed in Win 7. Just Q leads to bizarre behavior where it keeps bouncing back between command prompt and this vi or pseudo-win-vi thing.

Comment: Nothing appeared to work in posh-git. So I just exited. Ugh.

Comment: I have `core.pager = cat` in my `.gitconfig`, so git commands just print their output unless I explicitly pipe it through `less`.

Comment: pressing `q` works like a charm :)

Comment: `q` exits, but returns a non-zero value. `less` returns zero when exiting with `q`.

Comment: Good golly I should not have to read all the answers and comments to find the solution  for WINDOWS   `q:` is only thing that worked  per @ErikReppen comment.    I'm on Windows 10

Comment: If you need git log to return a value, for use in a script, you can flag `--no-pager`. So it'd be `git --no-pager log -1 --pretty='%B'`

Comment: this is so counter-intuitive, because we usually do `ctrl + c` to close

Comment: just press ( :qa ) without parentheses and hit Enter, it will exit.

Comment: By Hitting the Q worked :)

Comment: Wow knowing the existence of this `less` component, and its name, helped me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 150):

Actually, there are three ways to do it, precisely.

Type any of the following 3 commands.

1. **:**<kbd>q</kbd>
2. **:**<kbd>z</kbd>
   or
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> **+** <kbd>z</kbd>

P.S.: Sometimes, for someone, one of these options doesn't seem to work and for others it works.

Comment: I just had to press q since there is already **":"** added in the Git bash.

Comment: Are these vim commands?

Comment: in zsh on macOS `control+Z` will suspend the process, not terminate. Pressing `q` however works fine.

Answer (score 55):

Add following alias in the .bashrc file

```
git --no-pager log --oneline -n 10
```

- `--no-pager` will encounter the (END) word
- `-n 10` will show only the last 10 commits
- `--oneline` will show the commit message, ignore the author, date information

Comment: `git --no-pager` is a thing I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: You can also do `GIT_PAGER=cat git diff` to use `cat` temporarily, or, alternatively to this, save it in your shell environment.

Answer (score 50):

You can press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit.

`git hist` is using a pager tool so you can scroll up and down the results before returning to the console.

Answer (score 36):

The `END` comes from the pager used to display the log (your are at that moment still inside it). Type <kbd>q</kbd> to exit it.

Answer (score 11):

I wanted to give some kudos to the comment that mentioned CTRL + Z as an option. At the end of the day, it's going to depend on what system that you have Git installed on and what program is configured to open text files (e.g. less vs. vim). CTRL + Z works for vim on Windows.

If you're using Git in a Windows environment, there are some quirks. Just helps to know what they are. (i.e. Notepad vs. Nano, etc.).

Comment: I wouldn't have considered using a graphical program such as Notepad with one like Git that runs in a terminal.

Comment: Ctrl-Z on Unix-like platforms leaves the process present but stopped; this only makes sense on Windows (to the extent that anything at all makes sense on Windows).

Answer (score 8):

In this case, as snarly suggested, typing <kbd>q</kbd> is the intended way to quit `git log` (as with most other pagers or applications that use pagers).

However normally, if you just want to abort a command that is currently executing, you can try <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> (doesn't seem to work for `git log`, however) or <kbd>ctrl+z</kbd> (although in *bash*, <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd> will freeze the currently running foreground process, which can then be thawed as a background process with the `bg` command).